# Google APIs (Analytics) Access Token and Refresh Token Errors on New Account

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am having issues with using a stored refresh_token from Google APIs to grant a new access_token.

Our sign-up flow guarantees that only one account is authed with our client. When testing locally with a Google Account I control, I receive an access_token and refresh_token that is persistently stored. The access_token works to retrieve the necessary data prior to its expiration. If I try to refresh this access_token at any time following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) I receive an "invalid_grant" "Token has been expired or revoked.". I can verify that the account still has access through the admin panel. My refresh POST looks like:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com]&client_secret=[MY_CLIENT_SECRET]&refresh_token=[USER'S_REFRESH_TOKEN]&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Hitting this endpoint to verify the access_token:

```
GET /oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=[USER'S_ACCESS_TOKEN] HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
```

Yields information if the access token is not expired, but after it has expired I receive a 400 "Invalid Value" as expected.

Since I have been manually testing the refresh_token POST, I do not think there is a throttle happening on Google's side.

I have verified that we have access_type:offline during the sign up process. I am able to get all the requested data during the initial access_token period which leads me to believe the permissions are correct for the data we would like to access.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the issue you have having is with the number of outstanding refresh tokens

When a user authenticate your application you are giving a refresh token. If the user authenticate your application again you are given another refresh token.  Both tokens will continue to work.

You can do this up to 50 times after that the first one will stop working.    So make sure you are always saving the refresh token to the database

option 2

check the clock on the machine make sure you are insync with NTP

Option three

revoke the refresh token and request access again the user may have revoked your access.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I can verify that the new refresh token is persisted to the database when a user is authenticated. In fact, when I auth my test account, grab the refresh that occurs during the first auth, I still get an invalid_grant error when refreshing.

Comment: ok I have added two more options this is one of those errors that can be hard to nail down

Comment: I know the user has not revoked as I control the test account and can see the app in the admin panel.

My macbook is synced with apple servers properly, but I cannot tell how to see the sync status between there and google's servers.

I have followed most of the stack overflow answers for this issue, and none seem to fix the issue for me. 

Thanks for responding with more options.